# display div tag only if post has thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I would like to display post thumbnail and excerpt side by side but even if post hasn't got a thumbnail its div still there to be seen. How could I disappear thumbnail's parent div?

So far I've tried following but did not work.

```
<!-- post thumbnail -->
        <?php if( has_post_thumbnail()) : { ?>
        <div class="thumb-image">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Is the div the `<div class="thumb-image">`? Your code looks right but it has invalid PHP syntax, an if statemen needs to be `if ( ) {}` or `if () :  endif;` not `if () : { } endif;`

Comment: @TomJNowell yes it is the div classed thumb-image I want to hide if there is no thumnnail of post.

Comment: if you mean this syntax `<?php if( has_post_thumbnail()) :  ?>
        <div class="thumb-image">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
     
<?php endif; ?>` doesn't change anything.

Comment: I think my post was problematic, I've created a fresh post with no thumbnail it works now thank you after all.

Comment: The code in your comment is better than what's in your question, the code in your question will generate PHP syntax errors